# Good simple equation to interpolate this curve?

Tags: graphing-functions, curves, interpolation

I am trying to roughly interpolate a smooth curve of this shape for an audio synthesis project:
[image: Decay Curve]

For example, a y=1/x curve yields an okay approximation but it's a bit too steep at the left and/or doesn't flatten out enough on the right:

[image: Decay Curve 1/x]

Is there any other simple way to get this approximate shape you can think of?

The article this comes from is using these two equations:

[image: Equation 21]
[image: Equation 22]

They state: "A linear regression of Eq. (21) with ssyn instead of spick gives the “synthesized T30.”"

However, I don't need the exact equations. Just a rough approximation of the general shape. Any thoughts?

---

Edit: Someone suggested exp which looks nice:

[image: exp]

I think that's probably the most right simple answer. But still open to further suggestions.

Comment: Which other types of functions have you tried? Maybe exp function?

Comment: Hey thanks man. I think that looks good. I added exp to the question so you can see. Probably that's the right solution.

Comment: I don't think there will be a "right" solution unless one knows the context in which the graph arises. So I'm not quite sure that you will get a conclusive solution here.